# Example of a very insecure ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security

I am looking for a very insecure ASP.NET application.  Ideally i'm looking for an application that was written by a noob who has made a lot of security mistakes.   If the app has a MS-SQL back-end that would be a bonus.   I know of two cool projects for [PHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvwa/) and [J2EE](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project) which fill my needs.   Do you know anything like this for ASP.NET?

Comment: hmmm, not sure many people will be rushing to nominate their apps!

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com  
(I mean the articles on the site, not the site itself!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Hacme Bank](http://www.foundstone.com/us/resources/proddesc/hacmebank.htm) is a pretty good example from [Foundstone](http://www.foundstone.com/us/index.asp) of what **not** to do. It's an older example, written in .NET 1.1 against SQL 2000, but covers most of the common vulnerabilities found in web applications.

Answer (score 1):

I know one... there's a business near where I live, and I refuse to join their loyalty program because I accidentally stumbled across a SQL injection vulnerability on their site. I can't tell you who it is though, because they're a real business and I'm sure they don't want your students to hack them.

Why not write your own? Maybe start a codeplex project called LearnSecurity, which has a combination of pages - some which use bad security practices and some which don't.

Comment: Well said. My guess his main intent is to demonstrate the weakness of ASP.NET. While writing a vulnerable app in ASP.NET is easy, it not easy to write a good one that demonstrates the weakness of ASP.NET and other Microsoft technologies.

Comment: "My guess his main intent is to demonstrate the weakness of ASP.NET."  -- you mean the weakness of any web application created by an inexperienced or otherwise inept developer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Rob suggested ... you could make a couple of pages ... on the first get the input from a field and execute it against the database :) On the second, just get some text from the db that contains javascript alert or something and render it directly on the page :) Just an idea ...

Answer (score 0):

You can search the vulnerabilities databases, like [NISTs one](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search).